# Legacy OpenGL - Blending textures on water reflections produced with stencil test

Tags: opengl, legacy, blending, stencil-buffer

I'm forced to use legacy OpenGL and no shaders for an academic project (yes..).
I'm rendering a 3D world with mountains and water. My goal (and problem) is to draw the skydome as reflection on the water. The skydome itself has 2 textures (night and day) which are drawn blended based on an alpha value as follow:

```
void Renderer::drawSkydome()
{
   // Enable blending
   glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    // Disable depth testing
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
    
    // Bind the vertex array object for the skydome
    glBindVertexArray(instance->objects[SKYDOME].vao);
    
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    
    // Day texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, instance->objects[SKYDOME].texture);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, instance->objects[SKYDOME].indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    
    glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, alpha);
    
    // Night texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, instance->objects[SKYDOME].blend_texture);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, instance->objects[SKYDOME].indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    
    glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    
    // Unbind the vertex array object and texture
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    
    // Re-enable depth testing
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

}
```

This just works fine. I then managed to draw objects reflections on water by using stencil test; specifically:

```
void Renderer::drawWater()
{
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    // Bind the water VAO
    glBindVertexArray(instance->objects[WATER].vao);
    
    // Enable two vertex arrays: co-ordinates and color.
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    
    glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST); // Enable stencil testing
    glClearStencil(0); // Set clearing value for stencil buffer.
    
    glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
    glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    
    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 1);
    glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE); // In all cases replace the stencil tag
    
    glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART);                                                       
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, instance->objects[WATER].indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glDisable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART);
    
    // Enable writing of the frame and depth buffers - actually drawing now begins.
    glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
    
    glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 1);
    glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP); // The stencil buffer itself is not updated.    
    
    glPushMatrix();
    
        glScalef(1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
        // Bind the vertex array object for the skydome
        glBindVertexArray(instance->objects[SKYDOME].vao);
        
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, instance->objects[SKYDOME].texture);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, instance->objects[SKYDOME].indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    
        glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, alpha); 
    
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, instance->objects[SKYDOME].blend_texture);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, instance->objects[SKYDOME].indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClie**ntState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        
        // Unbind the vertex array object and texture
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glPopMatrix();

    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST); // Disable the stencil test
    
    // Bind the water texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, instance->objects[WATER].texture);
    // Bind the water VAO
    glBindVertexArray(instance->objects[WATER].vao);
    
    glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART);                                                                 
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, instance->objects[WATER].indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glDisable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART);
    
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    
    // Unbind the vertex array object and texture
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}
```

The problem is this, the same piece of code (the one in between push and pop) for rendering the skydome which produces fine blending on the actual skydome, does not work when drawing skydome reflection on the water; specifically it only renders the night texture, no matter the value of Alpha. In other words I can't manage to draw blended day/night textures as reflection on the water (water texture itself btw has 0.5 alpha, so I'm able to see how the water texture blends with the skydome).
Is it due to some strange behaviour with the stencil test I'm not aware of?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: *"Is it due to some strange behaviour with the stencil test I'm not aware of?"* - No

Comment: Is `GL_ALPHA_TEST` enabled for some reason?

Comment: Nope! @Rabbid76

Comment: The stencil test does not care about the alpha channel. What is the blending function?

Comment: it looks like the glColor4f in between the push/pop section is not affecting the blending, both in alpha and rgb channels. As an alternative approach I tried setting alpha values individually and manually for each texel and re-upload the texture everytime; it obviously works but it is also much much slower. That's why I'm relying on that single glColor4f call; cleaner and faster

Comment: glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

set in the init routine

Comment: *"it looks like the glColor4f in between the push/pop section is not affecting the blending"* - Why should that be? `glPushMatrix`/`glPopMatrix` has nothing to do with the color. What is [`glTexEnv`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml)?

Comment: I was referring to the 2nd call of glColor4f, the one in the push/pop block. That is the one which doesn't result in any change on the blending. While the 1st call of glColor4f, the one in the drawSkydome() func, works just fine and regulates the blending between the 2 textures based on an alpha value.
I didn't set any environment parameter with glTexEnv (atleast I didn't need to when I wrote the drawSkydome func)

Comment: @Tides: It's not a troll answer. I'm just shaking my head in disbelief, that in this day and age, people in academia are still subjecting and forcing students to use the old, abandoned legacy API. This was not directed against you, but the people who gave you the assignment. Tell them this: No GPU you'll find in a computer that's not "retro" will not use shaders. That "shaderless" code you're writing… well that OpenGL state is translated into a shader on the backside of the driver regardless.

Comment: @datenwolf Yes, but that's the subject of another argument, maybe in a blog, not as answer under this stackoverflow question. In the matter, I completly agree with you; that's a waste of time for students.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible with the information provided in the question.

Comment: Well atleast I gathered the info that there is nothing fundamentally wrong with the code. Thank you for taking the time to inspect it; I'll look into it and provide a solution here when I manage to find one! :)

Comment: Is `glTexEnv` set anywhere else in your code? OpneGL is a state engine, once a state is set it is persistent and affects all pending statements.

Comment: It's not. And actually as time passes, the skydome (sphere) blending continues to work , switching from day to night and viceversa, while the reflected skydome stays still. So no state is being changed, otherwise it would affect the skydome sphere aswell

Comment: I think you put me in the right direction; something is wrong in other functions. I'll provide update here on what was the culpit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the solution was disabling GL_LIGHTING while rendering the reflected skydome as follows:

```
    glPushMatrix();
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING); // <-----------------------------
        glScalef(1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
        // Bind the vertex array object for the skydome
        glBindVertexArray(instance->objects[SKYDOME].vao);
        
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, instance->objects[SKYDOME].texture);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, instance->objects[SKYDOME].indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, alpha); 
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, instance->objects[SKYDOME].blend_texture);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, instance->objects[SKYDOME].indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        
        // Unbind the vertex array object and texture
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glPopMatrix();
```

Not sure how lighting was interfering with the blending, but adding that simple disable call solved my initial answer!. Feel free to provide more accurate explanations.

Comment: [`glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml), [`glColorMaterial`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColorMaterial.xml)

Comment: I'll look into it! kudos for the effort.